# PUT request alwasys returning 403 with grails rest call

Tags: java, rest, grails

I have really one weird bug in my application. Every PUT request failing and Giving response status 403. 
Below is configuration of my Grails app.

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0.M1"
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.M2"
```

Following is URL Mapping for action

```
put "/api/user/v1/User"  (controller:"userService", action:"addUser")
```

With same setting if i do request then i am getting 403.
But if i change url mapping to POST then it works.
Any help will be great

Comment: Best part is PUT works fine on Local. But when i deploy code to Tomcat 8 it simply return 403.

Comment: Try to trace request, maybe something change it before it came to tomcat

Comment: Did you find the problem to this?